# threejs mousedown handler breakes focus on input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js

this line of code in threejs

```
 document.addEventListener('mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false);
```

makes the input field to don't have focus when you click on it. For example on top of the page I have canvas with threejs stuff and on bottom of the page is contact form that doesn't work properly because of it.

I would like to keep this EventListener false because I need it to control the stuff in canvas. 
Is there a workaround to have mousedown on false and still have a normal focus on input when you click on it?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try call the focus for the form (using jquery):

```
 $('#myForm').on('click', function (e) {
        $("#myForm").focus();
   })
```

Edit:
maybe you can add the listener to the div that contains the canvas and not the whole document:

```
 canvasDiv.addEventListener('mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false);
```

Comment: Hi Lior, thank you for the answer, yes this should work, I have this option in my backup plan if I don't figure out how to disable focus for canvas only. I mean when you disable mousedown you can't select text for example, so it's not only input problem. I will accept this answer if there is no other way to disable it locally for canvas only.

Comment: good idea, I tried document.getElementsByTagName("canvas").addEventListener('mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false);

OR
document.getElementById("myId").addEventListener('mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false);

but for some reaseon it does not return false any more

Comment: ok, I ended up calling the focus on click, so I will accept the answer, thanks